# Why the electron of a lower energy orbit remain unstable at higher energy orbit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms

I am confused that, what makes an electron unstable in a higher energy orbit to revolve ?
As an electron have constant negative charge and defined masss then what is the property that is making the electron unstable ? Basically I want to ask the difference between the electron of a higher energy orbit and lower energy orbit .(except energy which is not an internal defined property of an electron like mass and charge)

Comment: If there is an available lower energy state than it can drop into it. And since it can it quite likely will.

Comment: It's not the electron that is unstable, it's the atom in the excited state.

Comment: @JonCuster, I think the question is *why* is it likely to drop into the lower state?

Comment: @ThePhoton - why does a ball drop when you release it?

Comment: @NickD thanks, that was the thing I was missing, It depends on atom not on the electron to keep atom stable

Answer (score 1):

It is because the electron and the nucleus interact with each other and other distant objects via EM interaction.

This is easiest to see in classical theory. The interaction between the particles is relativistic, delayed, which makes classical orbits from Newtonian mechanics unstable in most cases. The system nucleus+electron radiates EM energy away due to mutual correlated motion (orbiting), and this leads to approachment of the two particles. The retarded interactions act as damping force on the electron and nucleus, create an effective friction to the motion of both bodies.

In a naive model where there are only two particles in an empty universe, the friction eventually makes the electron fall on the nucleus, while it radiates infinite amount of energy in finite time (so this is obviously an unrealistic result). In a more complicated (but also more realistic) model with additional background EM radiation, the electron moves more erratically around the nucleus, the damping force  is still acting on the particles, but due to background radiation, the electron need not fall on the nucleus, it just gets closer to the nucleus on average, and in a long term, may end up in a sort of dynamic equilibrium, where it radiates as much (or better said, as very little) as it gets from the background radiation. This is hard to prove, but one can see intuitively why the random background radiation may prevent the electron from radiating infinite amount of energy in finite time.

In relativistic quantum theory of the atom, the higher states can change in time due to interaction with quantum EM field, even if that field is as "empty" or "low energy" as possible. So all excited states are considered as potentially unstable by default, even though some can live for a long time (which is how we explain fluorescence). Unless the whole system atom + nucleus is in a ground state of the whole system, completely isolated from the universe, the state of the system is expected to be unstable and to change in time.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons don't orbit. They occupy orbitals. Orbitals are eigenstates of the Coulomb hamiltonian, $H$, and as such are stationary states: that is, the only thing that changes with time is their (unobservable) phase. With that, all atomic states are indeed stable and do not transition.

Fortunately, $H$, is only an approximation (that works because electromagnetic is weak). There are addition terms that constitute a perturbing hamiltonian, $H'$, in particular, the electromagnetic field, which is dynamic. (The Coulomb term is static).

$H'$ couples the states (kind of like two weakly coupled pendulums), which allows transitions that combined by the spontaneous emission of a photon.